# affine transformation preserves the property of parallelism among lines

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, affine-geometry

I'm a bit confused about when vectors are parallel. I was trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $f(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$ be an affine transformation. Then $f$ preserves the property of parallelism among lines

In the solution they said that

> Suppose that $l\,:\, \vec{p}_{1}+t\vec{u}_{1}$ and $m\,:\,\vec{p}_{2}+t\vec{u}_{2}$ when $t\in\mathbb{R}$ are parallel lines. Then $\vec{u}_{2}=k\vec{u}_{1}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then they showed that:

$$
T\left(\vec{p}_{1}+t\vec{u}_{1}\right)=A\left(\vec{p}_{1}+t\vec{u}_{1}\right)+\vec{b}=\left(A\vec{p}_{1}+\vec{b}\right)+t\left(A\vec{u}_{1}\right)\\
T\left(\vec{p}_{2}+t\vec{u}_{2}\right)=A\left(\vec{p}_{2}+t\vec{u}_{2}\right)+\vec{b}=\left(A\vec{p}_{2}+\vec{b}\right)+\left(tA\vec{u}_{2}\right)=\left(A\vec{p}_{2}+\vec{b}\right)+tk\left(A\vec{u}_{1}\right)
$$
So if $\vec{q}_{1}\triangleq A\vec{p}_{1}+\vec{b}$, $\vec{v}\triangleq A\vec{u}_{1}$ and $\vec{q}_{2}\triangleq A\vec{p}_{2}+\vec{b}$, you get:
$$
T\left(\vec{p}_{2}+t\vec{u}_{2}\right)=\vec{q}_{2}+t\left(k\vec{v}\right)
$$
This means that $\vec{q}_{1}+t\vec{v}_{1}$ and $\vec{q}_{2}+kt\vec{v}$ are parallel.

My question is - why $l$ and $m$ are parallel? Why $\vec{q}_{1}+t\vec{v}_{1}$ and $\vec{q}_{2}+kt\vec{v}$ are parallel? What make those kind of vectors of form $\vec{a}+t\vec{b}$ parallel?

Edit: The solution (with changes to names of variables) is located [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/books/meg/meg_ch12.pdf) (page 260).

Comment: @coudy You are right, my mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: You should draw a picture of this. Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$, then draw the set $\{t v \ | \ t\in \mathbb{R} \} $, then pick $q\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and draw the set $\{q+ tv \ | \ t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. You should also check what happens when you pick $w=c v$, with $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $c\neq 0$.